# Windows 10 Lock Screen image as Desktop Wallpaper

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

Windows 10 when locked covers the whole screen with an image that changes periodically.

How can I make it so that whatever image is on the Windows 10 lock screen is also my desktop background/wallpaper? This of course means that when the lock screen image changes, the wallpaper should change to that too.

Comment: You would have to manually set the desktop wallpaper each time the Spotlight image changed.

Comment: [How to Save Windows 10’s Lock Screen Spotlight Images to Your Hard Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/247643/how-to-save-windows-10s-lock-screen-spotlight-images-to-your-hard-drive/). That article explains where the files are located in.  It would be a simple enough task to create a powershell that automates the conversion of the file to .jpg and then sets the desktop to the most recent image.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little python 3 script which copies the pictures that are available to a designated background folder. It requires that you create a designated folder to store the pictures in and you need to update the path to match your own user.

https://github.com/Maximusnor/Windows-background
It requires python3 + some packages to use

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd party window manager Display Fusion gives you options to change this.

I myself use it so that the lock screen is merely a clock.

Why? Because I haver to sleep with the TV on for HDMI issues. So i want a black screen.  It took me awhile to figure this out.  DisplayFusion let me put just the clock on there, which was kind of nice and not so room-brightening that it's hard to sleep.